# Validate Getter and Setter Access Modifier Enforcement During Visualforce Expression Language Parsing

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a doubt on 'Validate Getter and Setter Access Modifier Enforcement During Visualforce Expression Language Parsing (Release Update)'

> To improve security, this update validates the Apex get or set method access modifier and throws an error if the Visualforce Expression Language can't invoke the method. When accessing Apex getter or setter methods defined by custom controllers, the Visualforce Expression Language incorrectly validates the access modifiers of the methods. Developers can sometimes access unauthorized get or set methods on Apex classes. This update was first available in Summer ’22 and is enforced in Winter ’23.

Question- Does this update apply to all visualforce pages or just the vf pages from managed package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a change in the core runtime, so it should affect Visualforce everywhere, including managed and unmanaged code, Classic and Lightning, Sites, Communities, Visualforce Email Templates, PagrReference.getContent, Visualforce Components, etc.